# Attach remove button to each rendered image in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of rendered images from a jquery photo editor. The list, however, is not currently setup to output the images in a list setup(i.e., `<li></li>`)

The current setup builds a "list" or rendered images as such:

```
renderButton.click(function (event) {
    var dataUrl;

dataUrl = imgly.renderToDataURL("png", { minSize: "300x300"}, function (err, dataUrl) {
     $("<img>").attr({
        src: dataUrl
      }).appendTo($(".result"));
    });
  });
```

This merely appends images to a `<div class="result"></div>`

How can I attach a button to each image to remove it from the list?

I can do the following to remove an item from a normal to-do list:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var item = $('input[name=additem]').val();
    $('ol').append('<li>'+ item +' <button id="remove">Remove</button></li>');
});

$("#remove").click(function(){
   $(this).parent('li').remove();
  });
});

$('#todolist').on('click', 'button', function(){
      $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

Comment: Provide your HTML code aswell. And even better - you can make a full example using [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: This is the most basic code necessary for the image cropper(though there's code running in the background needed to see the image): http://jsfiddle.net/k7apk9zh/

This is the code for a simple todo list with remove button:http://jsfiddle.net/k7apk9zh/1/

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/kg7sub7c/1/

Comment: There is syntax error in error (`});` after `reader.readAsDataURL(file);`). Do you miss something, or `});` can be safely deleted?

Comment: Thank you, @MelanciaUK! Just need to get it to not include more than one Remove button after each image now...

Comment: I've deleted my answer. I'm not sure what do you want. Some direction (code) to achieve this, or a way to fix the code provided.

Comment: The functionality is now working, but each subsequent image is given an additional button. So the second image has two, the third has three and so on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Here's an image of the issue I'm having: http://i.imgur.com/v3NigY0.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my issue:

```
image.appendTo($(".result"))
  $button = $('<button class="btn btn-default remove">')
        .text('Remove')
        .on('click', function () {
            image.remove();
            $(this).remove();
            return false;
        });
    $button.appendTo($(".result"));;

});
```